# Implementing of Stack using other datastructures like lists

Tags: python, stack

I have seen in many languages basically to implement stacks they take help of other data structure. Ex: If we need to implement stacks in python we cant take advantage of lists. A very simple example

```
class Stack(object):


def __init__(self):
    self.stack = []

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.stack == []

def push(self, element):
    self.stack.append(element)

def pop(self):
    return self.stack.pop()

def peek(self):
    return self.stack[len(self.stack) - 1]

def size(self):    
    return len(self.stack)
```

Point is does it even make sense to do that? if yes then how?

Comment: "does it even make sense to do that? if yes then how?" - what? Does it "make sense" to... use Python at all? Maybe use C++? Or whatever else?? You see, such questions don't make much sense themselves: what makes sense to you may be crazy for other people and vice versa.

Comment: Thats exactly I mean, using C or C++ completely makes sense but i have seen people using other languages and use other data structure to implement this , which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Whether it makes sense entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve. It does _not_ make sense if, e.g., you want to learn how a stack works. It _might_ make sense to wrap lists and other data structure if you want to make them more uniformly accessible in some lib of yours

Comment: So, are you asking "why other languages other than C and C++ exist"? You can use _dictionaries_ to implement a stack in Python. Even a string. You may even fiddle with literal bytes an object is comprised of and build a stack using just these raw bytes. You can have millions of implementations.

Comment: That's why the process of writing programs is called "development": you don't blindly execute the same instructions over and over again to produce, for example, some bread. You can create stuff _the way you want_, using whatever data structures you find useful here, using any programming language you want. This is a form of _art_, to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

In python, unless you really want to practice, it doesn't make any sense to implement your own stack. You can either use a list, even without a wrapper class, or you can use the deque class from collections. Deque is a generic data structure of stacks and queues:

[Collections deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Answer (score 0):

As with any other [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), the main points of implementing a data structure like, for example, a stack are:

- Provide a simple API with well-known operations.
- Hide the implementation details of the structure.

A secondary consequence that sometimes you get from this is that the structure is easier to use; sure no one would like to manually manage the elements of an array-based binary heap every time it has to be accessed, but that is not the main point to provide the type. In the case of a stack, it's pretty trivial to implement, so in that sense you don't win anything. What is it that you are getting then?

**Provide a simple API with well-known operations**

This is, I think, still not the most important aspect, but if you want to use a stack it is clearer to use stack operations (push, pop) than list operations. Specifically, it is good to have a limited interface that does *not* allow you to call forbidden operations, and/or that provides better errors and corner-case behaviour than a more generic approach.

**Hide the implementation details of the structure**

This is the key point. The most important thing of all this is that you don't need to (and cannot) know how the data structure is implemented, allowing you to change the implementation later on. Say you now want your stack to be persisted to disk; you would need add file read and write operations each time you push or pop something. Say now you want this storage to be distributed among several computers. Say you want to log every access. Say you want it to reside on GPU for some accelerated computation. All of these possibilities should support basic stack operations, but maybe not all of them support every list operation (or maybe you don't want to implement them all for each of them). As long as you maintain the same original interface, you will only need to make the minimal necessary changes to the implementation and the rest of the code should work exactly the same.

In a language like Python, which is quite high-level, dynamically typed and with a comprehensive standard library, these benefits are not so evident initially, but they still apply all the same.